# Perl: Faster way to split string by character

Tags: performance, perl, split

I am looking for a *way faster* solution to split a string into an array of values. The string has unfortunately `;` as a delimited character. Split seems to be quite slow when it comes for a set of > 1k strings and in-memory based solutions.

```
my (@array) = split(';', $string);
```

Is there any way to speed up Perl here (sort of workaround using `unpack` etc?)

**Update:**
Approx. 1500 `@members` take 0.6 - 0.8 seconds. (measured within the `foreach`) from  Having some dummy invalid `$ref` (without split), it's like real time. Maybe the `$ref`/`$redis` fills the time up? (using `RedisDB`)

Some code:

```
my $ref = $redis->execute("MGET", @members);    

foreach my $i (@members) { $counter++;

  my @result = split(';', $ref->[$counter]);    
  
  # approx. 30 comparisons/operations like:
  # if($result[0] == 1 && $result[7] == 1) {...}
}
```

Comment: Are the fields fixed-width?

Comment: No, there are not.

Comment: It might be worth showing (in addition to the short example is already showed, which is helpful) more code context in a separate section. It is possible that the optimization should take place there...

Comment: How do you know it's _way too slow_?

Comment: I have to agree with simbabque, it seems unlikely that `split` is the reason your program is slow.

Comment: Sure, I updated the post.

Comment: Those 0.6--0.8s for 1500 members works out to less than half a millisecond or so for one. How much better can one expect from a high-level function to split 1k into 100 segments?  If you want it _much_ faster it'd have to be tightly optimized XS code, no question.  (Btw, `spilt` itself is optimized and quite zippy.  I benchmarked this and found it to be a few times as fast as the regex that does the same.)  So ... I'd rather look for algorithmic improvements.

Comment: If your script is slow, it's not because of split. I just ran a split on 15,000 strings which are similar to yours and it took less than a tenth of a second.

Comment: Run some profiling, or run two for loops; first only to split strings, and second for your comparisons, in order to put things into a perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need all the fields, use `LIMIT`, as in: `split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT`. For example, this splits into 2 fields instead of as many as there are (I also removed the extra parens):

```
my @array = split ';', $string, 2;
```

Related to the above: According to `perldoc -f split`, one of the way to make it faster is to split into only as many fields as needed (and avoid splitting into an array without a `LIMIT`):

```
        In time-critical applications, it is worthwhile to avoid
        splitting into more fields than necessary. Thus, when assigning
        to a list, if LIMIT is omitted (or zero), then LIMIT is treated
        as though it were one larger than the number of variables in the
        list; for the following, LIMIT is implicitly 3:

            my ($login, $passwd) = split(/:/);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but we need all fields (90 in total). We could re-design the string however (other delimited character etc).

Answer (score 1):

You could try implement it in [XS](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs), for example:

```
#define PERL_NO_GET_CONTEXT
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#include "XSUB.h"
#include "ppport.h"
#define MOD_NAME "String::Split::Fast"

MODULE = String::Split::Fast  PACKAGE = String::Split::Fast
PROTOTYPES: DISABLE

AV *
split(str, sep_chr)
    SV *str
    SV *sep_chr
  CODE:
    if (DO_UTF8(str) || DO_UTF8(sep_chr)) {
         croak(MOD_NAME ": UTF-8 not implemented yet..");
    }
    // ...or if you use typemap: AV*   T_AVREF_REFCOUNT_FIXED
    //    You can avoid the call to sv_2mortal(), see: perldoc perlxs
    AV *array = (AV *)sv_2mortal((SV *)newAV());
    STRLEN seplen;
    const char *sep_chrs = SvPV(sep_chr, seplen);
    if (seplen != 1) {
        croak(MOD_NAME ": length of separator != 1");
    }
    const char sep = sep_chrs[0];
    STRLEN len;
    const char *buf = SvPV(str, len);
    const char *start = buf;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (buf[i] == sep) {
            SV *sv = newSVpvn(start, (STRLEN)(buf+i-start));
            av_push(array, sv);
            start = buf+i+1;
        }
        if (i == (len-1)) {
            SV *sv = newSVpvn(start, (STRLEN)(buf+i+1-start));
            av_push(array, sv);
        }
    }
    RETVAL = array;
  OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

I am not sure how much faster this will be yet..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. But is quite a huge Perl script and the stings come out of Redis Search etc. I guess the solution has be in native Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Using another delimiter is unlikely to help. Below is a benchmark that compares semicolon, blank, and the `NULL` character as delimiters. The speed is the same within the error of the benchmarking, regardless of the field delimiter used. Your speedup may have to come from the code used outside of the `split`.

Benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark;

my $num_fields = 90;
my @in_arr = map { rand } 1..$num_fields;

our $str_semicolon = join ';',  @in_arr;
our $str_blank     = join ' ',  @in_arr;
our $str_null      = join "\0", @in_arr;

timethese(1e6, {
    semicolon   => q{ my @out_arr = split ';',  $str_semicolon; },
    blank       => q{ my @out_arr = split ' ',  $str_blank;     },
    null        => q{ my @out_arr = split "\0", $str_null;     },
} );
```

Results:

```
Benchmark: timing 1000000 iterations of blank, null, semicolon...
     blank: 18 wallclock secs (17.60 usr +  0.03 sys = 17.63 CPU) @ 56721.50/s (n=1000000)
      null: 17 wallclock secs (17.23 usr +  0.02 sys = 17.25 CPU) @ 57971.01/s (n=1000000)
 semicolon: 17 wallclock secs (16.73 usr +  0.02 sys = 16.75 CPU) @ 59701.49/s (n=1000000)
```

I ran this using MacBook Pro, macOS 10.14.6 and perl v5.30.3.